# Is there a reason the poem tag exists?

Tags: discussion, tags

In the list of available tags there is the fairly popular [poetry](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poetry) tag, but there is also a tag for [poem](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poem). The [poem](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poem) tag has one question linked to it and no description specifying why or how it would be different than the [poetry](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poetry) tag. Not sure whether it is better for this tag to be removed or added as a synonym but thought I would ask here first.

Comment: I've retagged the one [tag:poem] puzzle as [tag:poetry]. I think the now unused [tag:poem] will self-destruct after a while.

Comment: Perhaps make them tag synonyms?

Answer (score 1):

What [poem](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poem) tag? [:-)](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6489/is-there-a-reason-the-poem-tag-exists#comment14528_6489)